# Why is Aluminum's 2nd ionization energy higher than Silicon's?

Tags: periodic-trends, periodic-table

According to the periodic table trend for I.E. Silicon should have a higher 2nd ionization energy than Aluminum so I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

Let us look at the electronic configurations of aluminum and silicon and their respective cations.

$\ce{Al}: [\ce{Ne}]\mathrm{3s^2\, 3p^1}$

$\ce{Si}: [\ce{Ne}]\mathrm{3s^2\, 3p^2}$

$\ce{Al^2+}: [\ce{Ne}]\mathrm{3s^1}$ It involves removing from $\mathrm{3s}$ sub shell

$\ce{Si^2+}: [\ce{Ne}]\mathrm{3s^2}$ It involves removing from $\mathrm{3p}$ sub shell

A $\mathrm{3p^1}$ electron has lower binding energy than that of $\mathrm{3s^2}$ electron.

It is due to more *screening effect* (as the predecessor sub-shells are higher in $\ce{Si}$) and *higher stability attained by having a completely filled $\mathrm{3s}$ sub-shell*